# i can't find enterprise manager

Tags: sql-server-express

i just installed the full sql server 2008 express on my machine and i can't find any link to run enterprise manager:

i went to here and installed the full package:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/

any clue or any suggestions to check what i may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download it separately and install it.

[Management studio link (2008)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out this very helpful [grid](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/) that shows other items your might want to download along with the base 2008 software. It includes components in addition to Management Studio that may be missing from your installation like full text search, reporting services, etc.  You can select exactly what you want to install and use Microsoft's Web Platform Installer to get it.  Also, just so you don't make the same mistake I did when looking for it at first - the name has changed from Enterprise Manager to Management Studio now.